# Can we use two auxiliary in one sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

a) Despite civic functionaries claiming that funds have been released, these projects are haven't taken off yet.

https://www.sott.net/article/295199-Attack-by-monkey-claims-womans-life-in-India

b) Our buses are haven't left yet, you can still get the bus.

1) Are above sentences constructions correct?

I mean can we use two two auxiliary i.e. are and havent in one sentence.

2)If Yes then above sentense is in simple or Passive tense?

Comment: You are mixing up some terminology— *simple* and *passive* are not tenses, and are not mutual variants of any other grammatical concept. Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You can have two auxiliary verbs in the same sentence:

> They **could have** gone to a quiet dinner, but they went walking on the beach instead.

but "are haven't" is never grammatical.  Pick one or the other, but not both:

> The buses **haven't left** yet, there's still time for you to get on.
>
> The buses **are not gone**, there's still time for you to get on.

[More about auxiliary verbs](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/auxiliaryverb.htm)

Comment: Thank Andrew ... What about first example ?

Comment: @user4084  As I said, "are haven't" is **never** grammatical.  Pick one or the other, and modify the sentence accordingly.

Comment: Sorry but you are giving ambiguous answer. In.first sentence You are saying "are haven't is not grammatical and in next sentence you say that u can pick up are or haven't but not both together. It is confusing me.

Comment: My question is " Are & haven't " and not "Are or haven't".

Comment: @user4084  I don't think my answer is ambiguous, but I can try to make it more clear:  Never use "are haven't".  It's not grammatical.  You can use "are not" or "have not",  *The projects **are not** yet successful* or *The projects **have not** yet become successful*.

Comment: Got it, Its mean my first example is also grammatically incorrect.

Comment: https://www.sott.net/article/295199-Attack-by-monkey-claims-womans-life-in-India

Comment: Link where i read my first sentence

Comment: It appears to be an editing error in that article. "*are haven't" would be an extremely unusual native speaker grammar error, but a perfectly common editing error, such as trying to change "...are planned to start in 2020" into "... haven't taken off yet".